# Get the length of a class list on cypress?

Tags: testing, cypress

Would there be a way to test for how many classes are within an element? I see methods for being able to test if an element has a class and testing length. Is there a way to combine these two together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
  cy.get('button')
    .invoke('attr', 'class')
    .then(classNames => classNames.split(' '))
    .should('have.length', 2);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide a part of the HTML I can customise the code for you, but it should be something like this:

```js
cy.get(<ELEMENT>)
  .find('class')
  .should('have.length', <NUMBER>)
```

This way you look for the , then look for the element 'class' within it. And verify that it present  of times.

Comment: it will not work, because of the `find` method, it gets the descendent DOM elements of a specific selector.